# Application doesn't start unless all output files are manually erased

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I work on a multi-project solution in visual studio 2010. Recently, one of my startup projects (a windows application) is having problems running: when I try to run it as usual I get the error:

```
ArgumentNullException was unhandled: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: activationContext
```

The only way I can run the project is by **deleting all files from the bin\debug folders**.

But: I have to do this manually, because **'Clean project' does not work properly either**: The .exe file is not erased (though other files are erased) and the aforementioned problem persists.

The error's stack trace:

*at System.Runtime.Hosting.ApplicationActivator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext activationContext, String[] activationCustomData)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssemblyDebugInZone()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()*

I'll appreciate your help on this matter, Thanks.

Comment: Not enough detail. What is `activationContext` and why is it `null`? What kind of project is the erroring project? Why does deleting all files solve the issue?

Comment: ActivationContext is a .NET library module, related to application activation. As I've written, the project is a windows application.

Regarding your other questions - I don't know yet why ActivationContext is null or why deleting the files helps, but I'm trying to figure it out, of course.

Comment: Debug + Exceptions, tick the Thrown box for CLR exceptions.  Post the stack trace of the exception.

Comment: I tried that, but the behavior didn't change (I'm guessing it's because the exception was thrown from external code and not my own). I'll post the exception stack trace though.

Comment: That's unhealthy.  Project + Properties, Debug tab, untick the "Enable the Visual Studio hosting process" option.  Tell us what that did.

Comment: I tried that, and surprisingly the application started normally this time. But then I re-enabled the hosting service - the application worked again. In fact, I can't reproduce the problem now (after it bugged me for 2 workdays, even after restart). I guess I can't be positively sure it had something to do with said checkbox (I haven't touched the code for a couple of hours prior). Anyway thank you very much for your help, and if the problem rises again I'll keep you all informed.

Answer (score 0):

If the exe is not erased it would suggest that there is still an instance of it running. Check in the TaskManager and kill any processes that are still running before starting a fresh one.

Comment: I am able to erase the exe manually, so it is not an issue of it already running.

Comment: @Tomata - That's not guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

Get sysinternal process explorer. Do a search on File/Handle for any file that is giving you issue. It will point to the executable that is still open. Right click on it and kill it. It will also kill a process quickly unlike Task Manager, which can take its time.
[Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896653)